# Cambio de Nombre Propiedad Analytics Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Estimados, necesito poder cambiar el nombre de la propiedad que me aparece en Google Analytics, este nombre proviene de Firebase Analytics y al parecer me toma el nombre del package, es posible cambiar este nombre en Google Analytics, a un nombre personalizado?

Comment: Hola Rodrigo, no me queda claro. Que es lo que queres cambiar?

Comment: Pasa una captura, sera mejor ;)